# App do not update view immediately though the property has been changed

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swiftui

I would appreciate a practical advice how to handle this problem, because I'm completely lost.

I have a Contentview presenting a task for user and three button with options for answer. Choosing any of the options user gets immediate response whether the answer right or wrong and a new task immediately presented. As well as, there are three counter that counts general number of answered tasks per session, and respectively number of right and wrong answers per session.

Also I have a toggle that is responsible to fix one of condition for following tasks.

The problem is, that once I click this toggle it accepts a new value, but it is reflected on new task only after user answers old task.  Simply speaking it works only with the next task, though I would like the view updated to new task with this fixed condition immediately and task presented before toggling wouldn't be counted as an answer.

*ContentView.swift*

```
    import SwiftUI
    import Combine

    struct ContentView: View {

        @EnvironmentObject var myVM: MyViewModel

        var body: some View {

            VStack (spacing: 5) {

                TitleView()

                Spacer()

                CountersAndToggleView()

                MainTaskView(numberOfPlayersInText: self.myVM.multiplayer, figureOne: self.myVM.figureOne, figureTwo: self.myVM.figureTwo)

                AnswerOptionsButtonsRow(option1: self.myVM.answerOpt_1, option2: self.myVM.answerOpt_2, option3: self.my.answerOpt_3, correctAnswer: self.my.correctAnswer)

         }
      }
```

*CountersAndToggleView.swift*

```
    import SwiftUI
    import Combine

    struct CountersAndToggleView: View {

        @EnvironmentObject var myVM: MyViewModel


        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                VStack {

                        CounterView(counter: myVM.masterCounter, progressIndicatorColor: .gray, backGroundColor: .white)
                        HStack {
                        CounterView(counter: myVM.correctCounter, progressIndicatorColor: .green, backGroundColor: .white)
                        CounterView(counter: myVM.wrongCounter, progressIndicatorColor: .red, backGroundColor: .white)
                    }
                }

                Spacer()

                VStack {
                    Text("Fix multiplayer")
                        .font(.system(size: 15, design: .rounded))

                    VStack {

                        Toggle("Multiplyer", isOn: $myVM.multiplayerFixed)
                                .labelsHidden()
                        }                 
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 45)
        }
```

*myViewModel.swift*

```
    import SwiftUI
    import Combine

    final class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {

        @Published var multiplayer: Int = 1

        @Published var figureOne: String = ""
        @Published var figureTwo: String = ""

        @Published var masterCounter = 0
        @Published var correctCounter = 0
        @Published var wrongCounter = 0

        @Published var multiplayerFixed: Bool = False

        init() {
             self.generateFigures()
             self.randomMultiplayer()
        }

        .... other functions
        }
```

I would like that once multiplayerFixed in CountersAndToggleView changed, the mainTaskView in ContentView would be fully updated assuming generations of new figures and value of multiplayer as it is fixed.

As I wrote, in reality it happens only after user answers previous task and push button.

Could you please advise what I do wrongly? and What should be changed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with code I realised how the solution should look like. Actually two things need to be done in `myViewModel.swift`:

1. The property didChange shall be declared

```
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
```

2. The property `@Published var multiplayerFixed: Bool = False` shall be changed with didSet

```
    var multiplayerFixed: Bool = false {didSet {reloadView()}}
```

3. `reloadView` function is a simple function included any code you need to be fulfilled once multiplayerFixed has been changed.  In my case:

```
    func reloadView() {
           self.generateFigures()
           self.randomMultiplayer()
    }
```

As simple as this.